# Appending to existing SQLite table when addition has fewer columns, without reading database into R

Tags: sql, r, sqlite, rsqlite

Is there some simple way, either on the SQL side or on the R side, to append a data.frame to an existing table that has more columns?  The missing columns should just be filled in with NAs.  Bonus points if it gracefully handles table 2 having more columns than table 1?

```
library(RSQLite)

# Create
db <- dbConnect( SQLite(), dbname="~/temp/test.sqlite" )

# Write test
set.seed(1)
n <- 1000
testDat <- data.frame(key=seq(n), x=runif(n),y=runif(n),g1=sample(letters[1:10],n,replace=TRUE),g2=rep(letters[1:10],each=n/10),g3=factor( sample(letters[1:10],n,replace=TRUE) ))
if(dbExistsTable(db,"test")) dbRemoveTable(db,"test")
dbWriteTable( conn = db, name = "test", value = testDat, row.names=FALSE )
testDat2 <- data.frame( key=seq(n+1,n+100), x=runif(100) )
> dbWriteTable( conn = db, name="test", value = testDat2, row.names=FALSE, append=TRUE  )
[1] FALSE
Warning message:
In value[[3L]](cond) :
  RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: table test has 6 columns but 2 values were supplied)
```

I could envision a wrapper for this as well. The algorithm would look something like:

1. Read 1 row from existing SQL table.
2. Get column names from that read.
3. Add column names to data.frame with the non-included names; fill with missings.
4. dbWriteTable now that the data.frame has the same columns as the SQL table.

That's simplified by the fact that SQLite has mutable class.  But I'd rather not reinvent the wheel if it already exists.

**EDIT**

Just a note to clarify: these datasets are large.  The SQL database will be about 30GB, and the data.frame (actually a `data.table` for obvious reasons) is about 4GB.  So solutions that require reading the SQL table into R are non-starters.

An alternative algorithm would be to do it in SQL:

1. Write R data.frame to a temporary SQL table.
2. SQL magic to append that table onto the main SQL table.
3. Delete temporary SQL table.
4. Profit.

Comment: Gracefully?  well, not really :-( Especially if you're appending a wider table to the original, which implies you've added parameters of some sort.  But for table2 < table1, maybe `table2<-cbind(table2,matrix(NA,nr=nrow(table2),nc=ncol(table1)-ncol(table2))` and then `rbind(table1,table2)`

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to read one table in pieces of, say, 1000 rows using dbSendQuery and add them in the other table (adding required columns).

```
res <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT * from tests")
while(!dbHasCompleted(res)) {
  data <- fetch(res, n = 1000);
  ### Put the data in the other table
}
```

There is also a way to do it in a single SQLite query. If you know which columns to add (fill with NULL) the SQL query would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO target_table SELECT col1,NULL,col2,col3,NULL,NULL,col4 FROM source_table
```

Comment: A little late, but +1 ;-).  That's exactly the approach I took in my answer above.  See the line: `dfColnames[ !sqlColnames %in% colnames(value) ] <- "null"`

Comment: Oh, I did not realize one of the answers was your own.

Comment: No worries.  Appreciate the help.  Nice answers in general by the way.  Have upvoted a few.

Answer (score 0):

`rbind.fill` from `plyr` offers a nice way to do this concatenation from within R:

```
require(plyr)
X <- rbind.fill(testDat, stDat2)
```

Not sure this quite answers your question though, since it looks like you want to do the append on the connection side.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft and Ryan - Unfortunately reading in the SQL table to R won't work--it's huge.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that also deals with factors:

```
#' Function to return column names from a SQLite database
#' @param conn An RSQLite connection to a database
#' @param name Character string giving the name of the table you want column names for
#' @export dbGetColnames
#' @return Character vector of column names
dbGetColnames <- function(conn, name) {
  x <- dbGetQuery( conn, paste0("SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE tbl_name = '",name,"' AND type = 'table'") )[1,1]
  x <- sub( "^.*\\((.+)\\).*$", "\\1", x )
  x <- str_split(x,",")[[1]]
  x <- gsub('[\t\n"]','', x)
  x <- gsub('^ *','', x)
  vapply( str_split( x ," " ), first, "" )
}

#' Write a table via RSQLite with factors stored in another table
#' Handles data.tables efficiently for large datasets
#' @param conn The connection object (created with e.g. dbConnect)
#' @param name The name of the table to write
#' @param value The data.frame to write to the database
#' @param factorName The base name of the tables to store the factor labels in in the SQLite database (e.g. if factorName is "_factor_" and the data.frame in value contains a factor column called "color" and the name is "mytable" then dbWriteFactorTable will create a table called mytable_factor_color which will store the levels information)
#' @param append a logical specifying whether to append to an existing table in the DBMS.
#' @param \dots Options to pass along to dbWriteTable (e.g. append=TRUE)
#' @return A boolean indicating whether the table write was successful
#' @export dbWriteFactorTable
#' @examples
#' library(RSQLite)
#' load_all( file.path(.db,"R-projects","taRifx") )
# Create
#' dbFilename <- tempfile()
#' db <- dbConnect( SQLite(), dbname=dbFilename )
# Write test
#' set.seed(1)
#' n <- 1000
#' testDat <- data.frame(key=seq(n), x=runif(n),y=runif(n),g1=sample(letters[1:10],n,replace=TRUE),g2=rep(letters[1:10],each=n/10),g3=factor( sample(letters[1:10],n,replace=TRUE) ))
#' if(dbExistsTable(db,"test")) dbRemoveTable(db,"test")
#' dbWriteTable( conn = db, name = "test", value = testDat, row.names=FALSE )
#' testDat2 <- data.frame( key=seq(n+1,n+100), x=runif(100) )
#' dbWriteTable( conn = db, name="test", value = testDat2, row.names=FALSE, append=TRUE  )
# Read test
#' testRecovery <- dbGetQuery(db, "SELECT * FROM test")
#' testSelection <- dbGetQuery(db, "SELECT * FROM test WHERE g3=='h' OR g3=='e' ")
#' testSelection
# Test removing rows matching criteria
#' for(i in 1:10) dbWriteTable( conn = db, name = "test", value = testDat, row.names=FALSE, append=TRUE )
#' dbSendQuery( db, "DELETE FROM test WHERE g3=='a'" )
#' # Test factor conversion
#' testDat <- data.frame(key=seq(n), x=runif(n),y=runif(n),g1=sample(letters[1:10],n,replace=TRUE),g2=rep(letters[1:10],each=n/10),g3=factor( sample(letters[1:10],n,replace=TRUE) ))
#' if(dbExistsTable(db,"test")) dbRemoveTable(db,"test")
#' if(dbExistsTable(db,"test_factor_g3")) dbRemoveTable(db,"test_factor_g3")
#' dbWriteFactorTable( conn = db, name = "test", value = testDat, row.names=FALSE )
#' dbGetQuery(db, "SELECT * FROM test")
#' dbGetQuery(db, "SELECT * FROM test_factor_g3")
#' testDat$g3 <- factor( sample(letters[6:15],n,replace=TRUE) )
#' dbWriteFactorTable( conn = db, name = "test", value = testDat, row.names=FALSE, append=TRUE )
#' dbGetQuery(db, "SELECT * FROM test_factor_g3")
#' if(dbExistsTable(db,"test")) dbRemoveTable(db,"test")
#' dbWriteFactorTable( conn = db, name = "test", value = as.data.table(testDat), row.names=FALSE )
#' dbReadFactorTable( conn = db, name = "test" )
#' dbReadFactorTable( conn = db, name = "test", query="WHERE g3=='a'" )
#' # -- Test merging of tables where the columns don't line up -- #
#' set.seed(1)
#' n <- 1000
#' testDat <- data.frame(key=seq(n), x=runif(n),y=runif(n),g1=sample(letters[1:10],n,replace=TRUE),g2=rep(letters[1:10],each=n/10),g3=factor( sample(letters[1:10],n,replace=TRUE) ))
#' if(dbExistsTable(db,"test")) dbRemoveTable(db,"test")
#' dbWriteFactorTable( conn = db, name = "test", value = testDat, row.names=FALSE )
#' dbGetQuery( db, "SELECT * FROM test" )
#' # Add a table with columns that are a subset of the SQL table
#' testDat2 <- data.frame( key=seq(n+1,n+100), y=runif(100) )
#' dbWriteFactorTable( conn = db, name="test", value = testDat2, row.names=FALSE, append=TRUE  )
#' dbGetQuery( db, "SELECT * FROM test" )
#' # Add a table where the columns are a superset of the SQL table's
#' testDat3 <- data.frame( key=seq(n+101,n+200), x=runif(100), n=runif(100) )
#' dbWriteFactorTable( conn = db, name="test", value = testDat3, row.names=FALSE, append=TRUE  )
#' dbGetQuery( db, "SELECT * FROM test" )
#' # Finish up
#' dbDisconnect(db) # close connection
#' unlink( dbFilename ) # delete tempfile
dbWriteFactorTable <- function( conn, name, value, factorName="_factor_", append=FALSE, ... ) {
  require(RSQLite)
  # Test inputs
  stopifnot(class(conn)=="SQLiteConnection")
  stopifnot(class(name)=="character")
  stopifnot("data.frame" %in% class(value))
  stopifnot(class(factorName)=="character")
  if( grepl("[.]",factorName) ) stop("factorName must use valid characters for SQLite")
  if( "data.table" %in% class(value) )  {
    dt <- TRUE # Is value a data.table, if so use more efficient methods
  } else {
    dt <- FALSE
  }
  # Convert factors to character
  factorCols <- names( Filter( function(x) x=="factor", vapply( value, class, "" ) ) )
  if(length(factorCols>0)) {
    for( cl in which( colnames(value) %in% factorCols ) ) {
      cn <- colnames(value)[cl]
      factorTable <- data.frame( levels=levels(value[[ cn ]]) )
      factorTable$levelKey <- seq(nrow(factorTable))
      fctNm <- paste0(name,factorName,cn)
      fctTableExists <- dbExistsTable( conn = conn , name = fctNm)
      # Write out the factor table
      if( append & fctTableExists ) {
        oldFactorTable <- dbGetQuery( conn = conn, paste("SELECT levelKey, levels FROM",fctNm) )
        levelExists <- factorTable$levels %in% oldFactorTable$levels
        if(!all(levelExists)) {
          startLevelKey <- max( oldFactorTable$levelKey ) + 1
          addLevels <- factorTable$levels[!levelExists]
          newFactorTable <- data.frame( 
            levels = addLevels,
            levelKey = seq( startLevelKey, startLevelKey + length(addLevels) - 1 )
          )
          dbWriteTable( conn = conn, name = fctNm, value = newFactorTable, row.names = FALSE, append = TRUE )
        } # If all levels exist, don't update the table -- go straight to converting the factor to character
      } else {
        if(fctTableExists) {
          warning(paste("Append set to FALSE but the factor table named",fctNm,"exists. Deleting."))
          dbRemoveTable( conn=conn, name = fctNm )
        }
        dbWriteTable( conn = conn, name = fctNm, value = factorTable, row.names = FALSE )
      }
      # Convert variable cl to character in the main data.frame (value) that we'll write to the main SQL table
      if( dt )  set( x=value, j=cl, value=as.character(value[[ cn ]]) )
    }
    if( !dt )  value <- japply( value, which( colnames(value) %in% factorCols ), as.character )
  } else {
    #warning("No factor columns detected.")
  }
  if( append ) {
    # If we're appending, check that the number of columns of the new table is equal to the number of columns of the old table
    # Only run this code if we're appending, because otherwise the table won't exist
    sqlColnames <- dbGetColnames( conn, name )
    colnamesSubset <- !all( sqlColnames %in% colnames(value) )
    colnamesSuperset <- !all( colnames(value) %in% sqlColnames )
    if( colnamesSuperset ) {
      addCols <- colnames(value)[ !colnames(value) %in% sqlColnames ]
      for( ac in addCols ) {
        warning(paste("Adding column",ac,"to SQL table"))
        dbSendQuery( conn,
                     paste(
                       "ALTER TABLE",
                       name,
                       "ADD COLUMN",
                       ac,
                       "DEFAULT NULL"
                     )
        )
      }
    } # If it's a superset but not a subset, then we're done (allow it to return back to the second if where it just writes value directly)
    if( colnamesSubset ) {
      # Write our database to a temporary table
      tempTableName <- "temp_dbWriteFactorTable"
      if(dbExistsTable(conn,tempTableName))  dbRemoveTable(conn,tempTableName)
      dbWriteTable( conn = conn, name=tempTableName, value = value, row.names=FALSE, append=FALSE  )
      # Add any columns to input data.frame that are in target table, then merge
      sqlColnames <- dbGetColnames( conn, name ) # Reset these now that we've possibly tinkered with them in the superset section
      dfColnames <- sqlColnames
      dfColnames[ !sqlColnames %in% colnames(value) ] <- "null"
      status <- dbSendQuery( conn, 
                             paste( 
                               "INSERT INTO", name, 
                               "(",paste(sqlColnames,collapse=","),")",
                               "SELECT",
                               paste( dfColnames, collapse="," ),
                               "FROM",
                               tempTableName
                             )
      )
      # Remove temporary table
      dbRemoveTable(conn,tempTableName)
    }
  } 
  if( !append || (append & !colnamesSubset) ) { # Either we're not appending, or the columns in the input and target tables exactly match (possibly after we added columns with the superset code)
    status <- dbWriteTable( conn = conn, name = name, value = value, append=append, ... )
  }
  return( status )
}

#' Read a table via RSQLite with factors stored in another table
#' @param conn The connection object (created with e.g. dbConnect)
#' @param name The name of the table to read
#' @param query A character string containing sequel statements to be appended onto the query (e.g. "WHERE x==3")
#' @param dt Whether to return a data.table vs. a plain-old data.frame
#' @param factorName The base name of the tables to store the factor labels in in the SQLite database (e.g. if factorName is "_factor_" and the data.frame in value contains a factor column called "color" and the name is "mytable" then dbWriteFactorTable will expect there to be a table called mytable_factor_color which holds the levels information)
#' @param \dots Options to pass along to dbGetQuery
#' @return A data.table or data.frame
#' @export dbReadFactorTable
dbReadFactorTable <- function( conn, name, query="", dt=TRUE, factorName="_factor_", ... ) {
  require(RSQLite)
  # Test inputs
  stopifnot(class(conn)=="SQLiteConnection")
  stopifnot(class(name)=="character")
  stopifnot(class(factorName)=="character")
  if( grepl("[.]",factorName) ) stop("factorName must use valid characters for SQLite")
  # Read main table
  if( dt ) {
    value <- as.data.table( dbGetQuery( conn, paste("SELECT * FROM",name,query), ... ) )
  } else {
    value <- dbGetQuery( conn, paste("SELECT * FROM",name,query), ... )
  }
  # Convert factors to character
  factorCols <- sub( paste0("^.*",name,factorName,"(.+)$"), "\\1", 
                     Filter( Negate(is.na), 
                             str_extract( dbListTables( conn ), paste0(".*",name,factorName,".*") ) 
                     )
  )
  if( length(factorCols>0) ) {
    for( cn in factorCols ) {
      fctNm <- paste0(name,factorName,cn)
      factorTable <- dbGetQuery( conn, paste0("SELECT * FROM ",fctNm) )
      factorLevels <- factorTable$levels[ order( factorTable$levelKey ) ] # sort by levelKey so we maintain a consistent reference category (SQL databases don't guarantee the row order remains the same)
      if( dt ) {
        cl <- which( colnames(value) %in% cn )
        set( x=value, j=cl, value=factor( value[[ cn ]], levels=factorLevels ) )
      } else {
        value[[ cn ]] <- factor( value[[ cn ]], levels=factorLevels )
      }
    }
  } else {
    #warning("No factor columns detected.")
  }
  value
}
```

This will show up in `taRifx` at some point, I suspect.  The part that I added to solve this question is the `if(colnamesSubset)` block.